# Create a array of shared_ptr with objects

Tags: arrays, c++11, object, shared-ptr

I'm new to using smart pointers, I'm trying to create the same but I have errors.

```
    class data{
private:
    int ID;
public:
    void setID(int a){
        ID=a;
    }
    int getID(){
        return ID;
    }};

   int main(){
    data d*;
    d=new data[30];
    for(int i=0;i<30;i++){
      (p+i)->setID(i);
   }}
```

I try with:

```
shared_ptr<data> sp( new data[30]);
 for(int i=0;i<30;i++){
    sp->setID(i)[i];
}
```

Error:invalid types 'void[int]' for array subscript|

```
shared_ptr<data> sp( new data[30]);
for(int i=0;i<30;i++){
    (sp+i)->setID(i);
}
```

Error: No match for 'operator+' (operand types are 'std::shared_ptr' and 'int')|

how can i do the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you're trying to add `i` to `sp`, instead of to the pointer that is managed by `sp`. What you want to do is use [`get()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/get) to get the stored pointer first:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
  sp.get()[i].setID(i);
}
```

If you use C++17, there's also [`operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator_at) which you could use.

However, you've got another problem (and `operator[]` wouldn't work because of it). You are storing the result of `new[]` in a `std::shared_ptr` which expects to manage a pointer returned by `new`. Your construction of `sp` should actually be:

```
std::shared_ptr<data[]> sp(new data[30]);
```

Otherwise you'll get undefined behavior, because `sp` is going to call `delete` on the address returned by `new data[30]`, whereas it needs to use `delete[]`. Here's a bunch more info about the constructors of [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr).

*Side notes:*

1. Please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for your questions.
2. Are you sure you need `std::shared_ptr`? Won't [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) work? `std::unique_ptr` is basically as fast as a raw pointer, whereas `std::shared_ptr` is slower.